# Pagination by combining two query results

Tags: java, optimization, pagination

There are currently two query lists, let's assume one is List queryList1 and  List queryList2, where

```
Line1: queryList1 = dao.get(someParams); 
Line2: queryList2 = dao.get(differentParams);
```

I can execute Line 2 based on the following conditions

```
if(queryList1.size() == request.size()) { //some computation with queryList2 }
if(queryList1.isEmpty()) { //some computation with queryList2}
if(queryList1.size() < request.size()) { //some computation with queryList2}
```

And this is how the computation in queryList2 looks like

```
if(queryList2.size() == request.size()) { //some computation  }
if(queryList2.isEmpty()) { //some computation}
if(queryList2.size() < request.size()) { //some computation }
```

So there a lot of conditional branching happening here, to do pagination for combination of two types of query results. Is there any better way to do this?

P.S. We can't do a union on the query results by combining the dao layers. These two dao layer calls has to run separately on need basis

Example for Reference:

```
queryList1 = {C1, C2, C3, C4, C5}
queryList2 = {P1, P2, P3, P4, P5}
When: Pagination size is 3, I need to return 3 records every page
Page1 results: {C1, C2, C3}
Page2 results: {C4, C5, P1} -> if queryList1 size becomes less than page requested size or is equal to 0, only then fetch queryList2
Page3 results: {P2, P3, P4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list different from main list populated by queries. Then add your query results accordingly
.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I am creating a different list already. So the question basically is on how to optimise the branching conditions on each of these lists which I do, when adding to the main list

Comment: given, you know what kind of content you want in your list. Use a for loop to filter through the data and sort.

Comment: I have added an example for reference